# How to open .NEF raw files(Nikon Raw Files) in windows 10 without lightroom?

Tags: canon, nikon, raw, file

How can I open Nikon Raw files in my windows 10 PC without any lightroom or photoshop. The files have extension .NEF
I know I can open canon raw file in my windows 10 by just double clicking them..They are in .CR2 format. But I cannot open Nikons raw files with double clicking on them. It says file not supported. Please I need help.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by open them? Which software open CR2 files?

Comment: @RomeoNinov There are codecs you can install that will allow windows native apps (like Explorer and their multiple image viewers) to view CR2 files. It allows you to see thumbnails of your images, for instance, in the File view.

Comment: @Robin, I use XNview and do not need drivers at all. The main question was what OP want to do with those files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should download the Nikon NEF Codec from their homepage:

https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/de/products/170/NEF_Codec.html

Then you can open NEFs without any additional programs.

Answer (score 1):

- AFAIK Nikon cameras are sold with a free version of the Nikon Capture software (or you can get it from some Nikon site).
- There are several free applications that can open/process "raw" files from about any camera: RawTherapee, Darktable, PhotoZone, PhotoFlow, NuFraw, some also being usable as plugins for the Gimp image editor. Many of these are discussed [here](https://discuss.pixls.us/)

Comment: It appears the OP is looking for the ability to open the raw in native windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

The famous IrfanView has an extension to show NEF files.

You can also convert (or batch convert) NEF files to any other format you would wish, using IrfanView.